# persist route when gateway is from another subnet

Tags: redhat, route

When I want to create route when gateway is from another subnet I have to execute two commands:

```
   route add -host 10.10.100.17 eth0
```

for adding gateway, and:

```
   route add -net 10.210.0.0/16 gw 10.10.100.17
```

to add a route to network using previously defined gateway

The problem is when I wan to persist this route. I am trying to do it in */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0*

Content of file:

```
10.210.0.0/16 via 10.10.100.17
```

But I end up with error:
**Bringing up interface eth0:  RTNETLINK answers: No such process**

How can I add a host gateway ?

UPDATE:

I tried also with syntax

```
ADDRESS0=10.210.0.0
NETMASK0=255.255.0.0
GATEWAY0=10.10.100.17
```

But there is still error. Problem is with 10.7.233.17 gateway. As I mentioned before after command  **route add -host 10.10.100.17 eth0** it works fine, but I don't know how to add host **10.10.100.17** in */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0*

**UPDATE2:**
Checked with

```
ADDRESS0=10.10.100.17
NETMASK0=255.255.255.255
GATEWAY0=<MY_IP>

ADDRESS1=10.210.0.0
NETMASK1=255.255.0.0
GATEWAY1=10.10.100.17
```

But still error.

**route -n** after network restart produce:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.100.17     <MY_IP>     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

**route -n** after command **route add -host 10.10.100.17 eth0** produce:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.100.17     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

So i tried with

```
ADDRESS0=10.10.100.17
NETMASK0=255.255.255.255
GATEWAY0=0.0.0.0
```

But error still exist, btw **route -n** after network restart produce this same output as after **route add -host 10.10.100.17 eth0** command. I am totally confused...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ADDRESS0=10.10.10.17
NETMASK0=255.255.255.255
GATEWAY0=<your eth0 ip here>

ADDRESS1=10.210.0.0
NETMASK1=255.255.0.0
GATEWAY1=10.10.100.17
```

Comment: It doesn't help, see my update

Comment: Edited my answer - try that one. The first block should add a route to the host 10.10.10.17 using eth0 so you can use it in the second block.

Comment: unfortunately still error, see my updates